# Delay Returning Position CSS3 Transition

Tags: html, css, transition

Is there a way to delay a div transition when it's animating back to it's original state, but not when it's starting to animate?

Ex:

```
[ ] <- hover over this
[     ] <- immediately changes to this
[     ] <- stop hovering, stays like this for a second or two
[     ]
[     ]
[     ] <- then animates back to original state
[    ]
[   ]
[  ]
[ ]
```

Comment: You mean without any Javascript / jQuery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. You can redefine the animation in the hover state.

```
selector {
    property: value1;
    transition: property 1s 1s linear; /* transition: property duration delay easingfunction; */
}
selector:hover {
    property: value1;
    transition: none; /* No animation */
}
```

Don't forget to add vendor-prefixes. Futher informtation on: [transitions & CSS3](http://www.css3files.com/transition/), [auto vendor prefixer](http://cssprefixer.appspot.com/).

Comment: That kind of worked, but it worked backwards :o now if you hover over it, it delays, but if you stop hovering, it immediately changes back. I'll play around with it, but I'd appreciate it if someone could try and work it out, too.

Comment: Got it, you just needed to switch those. This is the way that I did it: selector {transition-delay:1s;} selector:hover {transition-delay:0;} and it works perfectly.